# intermittent blank screens when restarting app, using React native navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

I am using [React native navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) `V:"^1.1.334"` to handle routing within my app. I am currently rendering a Login screen initially and then dispatching an action using redux/redux-saga to change the state depending whether the user is logged in or not. I am experiencing issues in my release build where after sometime, if I reset the app, it will just render a blank screen and nothing gets on the screen and the only way to fix it, it to completely wipe the app's data and cache. Forcing the app to stop does not work. I imagine there are many possible causes but I highly suspect it may be with the way I am implementing the login screen logic to switch to the protected content. I have a pretty standard  index.js

```
var store = configureStore();

registerScreens(store, Provider); // this is where you register all of your app's screens

// start the app
Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
    screen: {
        screen: 'myapp.Login',
        navigatorStyle,
    },
    drawer: { // optional, add this if you want a side menu drawer in your app
        left: { // optional, define if you want a drawer from the left
            screen: 'myapp.Drawer', // unique ID registered with Navigation.registerScreen
            fixedWidth: 600, // a fixed width you want your left drawer to have (optional)
        }
    }
});
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('TrackPlayer', 
    () => require('./app/modules/player/player-handler.js')(store));
```

And then in my login screen I have the auth logic

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.props.actions.checkAuth();
}

render() {
  if (this.props.user.isAuth) {
    this.props.navigator.resetTo({
      screen: 'myApp.Player',
      navigatorStyle :{
        navBarHidden: true,
      }
    });

    return null;
  }

  return (<LoginScreen />);
}
```

The `checkAuth` function dispatches an async action and then if the user is authenticated, the state is changed via redux and `user.isAuth` is updated which will reset the app. I assume that the problem is that perhaps I can't reset the 
app while the main screen is still rendering? because maybe it triggers some sort of racing condition and nothing gets rendered?

So my question is whether placing this logic inside the render method can conflict and if so, where should said logic be implemented? Or could this be an issue with react-native-navigation?

I've checked the output from log-android (since its a release build) and the output seems identical when the app renders correctly and when it doesn't so at least there aren't any errors being explicitly thrown.

Heres what that looks like, if you're curious. Also could it be that I am also launching my app as a `singleTask`? should it be something else? I changed it because I've been having problems with the app returning from the background when the back button is pressed, which that did not solve. That's for another question though.

```
07-24 15:35:19.703  4150  4150 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.ctor()
07-24 15:35:19.715  4150  4150 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground()
07-24 15:35:19.715  4150  4150 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()
07-24 15:35:19.720  4150  4150 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundFromBundleLoader()
07-24 15:35:19.720  4150  4150 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground()
07-24 15:35:19.720  4150  4150 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread()
07-24 15:35:19.811  4150  4169 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext()
07-24 15:35:20.158  4150  4169 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge.
07-24 15:35:20.163  4150  4169 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge before initializeBridge
07-24 15:35:20.172  4150  4169 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge after initializeBridge
07-24 15:35:20.173  4150  4169 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle()
07-24 15:35:20.199  4150  4178 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext()
07-24 15:35:20.200  4150  4178 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.initialize()
07-24 15:35:21.547  4150  4150 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()
07-24 15:35:21.559  4150  4177 I ReactNativeJS: Running application "uplayer.Drawer" with appParams: {"initialProps":{"screenInstanceID":"screenInstanceID4","navigatorID":"navigatorID3_nav","navigatorEventID":"screenInstanceID4_events"},"rootTag":1}. __DEV__ === false, development-level warning are OFF, performance optimizations are ON
07-24 15:35:21.593  4150  4150 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()
07-24 15:35:21.729  4150  4177 I ReactNativeJS: Running application "uplayer.Login" with appParams: {"initialProps":{"screenInstanceID":"screenInstanceID2","navigatorID":"navigatorID1_nav","navigatorEventID":"screenInstanceID2_events"},"rootTag":11}. __DEV__ === false, development-level warning are OFF, performance optimizations are ON
07-24 15:35:22.330  4150  4177 I ReactNativeJS: Cookie doesn't contain sid [object Object]
07-24 15:35:24.216  4150  4177 I ReactNativeJS: isPurchased false
```